# Import a CVS repository into GIT results in some misleading behaviors related to timestamps

Tags: git, timestamp, cvsimport

I have used `git cvsimport` to import my CVS repository into a brand new GIT one.

Unfortunately, in some cases some commits have been reported in a wrong order.

E.g. I had two CVS revisions of a file, rev1.1 at 11.39am and rev1.2 at 11.42am; in GIT, I can see a commit at 11.42am (with content equal to rev1.2) and a subsequent one at 11.45am (with content equal to rev1.1).

I'm aware of the known issue stated in the cvsimport man page

> If timestamps of commits in the cvs repository are not stable enough to be used for ordering commits changes may show up in the wrong order.

but I cannot understand what does **stable enough** mean.

Moreover, it would be great if anyone could provide me a workaround for this problem.

Thank you very much

cghersi

Answer (score 0):

Is very easy to cheat git into timestamp, as it checks only the local time, so probably the cvs checked the time into the order the tags was set.

But a workaround to this is use [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick). This commands is almost a copy-paste from commits, so you can simple give a `checkout` to a commit from rev1.1 and there use the `cherry-pick` into the commit lost after the rev1.2. Than after use a `rebase -i` just to erase/squash the duplicated commit after the rev1.2. As using rebase/cherry-pick, the commit's tree will request a sad `push -f` into the branch to fix everything.